# How to change vec value of elements by index?

Tags: for-loop, vector, rust

```
let mut vec1 = vec![0,0,0,0];
let vec2 = vec![1,3,2,0];

for v in vec2.iter(){
   vec1[v] += 1;
}
```

My example does not work. How do I change values correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your index is behind a reference and it needs to be of type `usize`, so make sure you destructure it:

```
for &v in vec2.iter(){
   vec1[v] += 1;
}
```

And also to be safe, explicitly cast `v` as `usize`:

```
for &v in vec2.iter(){
   vec1[v as usize] += 1;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c138dca18d0db8504d4f1434f27e8911).

Comment: The fix is adding `&`. `as usize` can be deleted without effect.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Hmm, interesting. Is this a latest change?

Comment: I guess the first state of this answer was the accurate one.  Yes it  can be deleted but maybe reason might be explained in here? Because when you put `v` as index  `vec2`'s  type will be  inferred as `Vec<usize>`, if one defines `vec2`  as explicitly like `Vec<u16>` it would not work

Comment: Still want to point: IMO defining `v2` 's type explicitly `Vec<usize>` will be the safest,  since  `v2` keeps the indices ^^.

Answer (score 3):

This will run and print `[1,1,1,1]`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut vec1 = vec![0,0,0,0];
    let vec2 = vec![1,3,2,0];

    for v in vec2.iter(){
        vec1[*v] += 1;
    }
    
    dbg!(vec1);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6edf518d6e1c344d7f33665ad6e17318)